# Full list of possible classnames added by Modernizr?

Tags: modernizr

Where can I find such a full list?

I can tell there are .js and .no-js , .touch and .no-touch.

But .opacity -- is there .no-opacity or just missing .opacity means no support?  This is just an example.  A full list helps me a lot in writing code for those devices that I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Modernizr detects will add `.<feature>` if supported and `.no-<feature>` if not. The set of detects depends on the custom build settings you chose in [the downloader](http://modernizr.com/download).

In the source of every Modernizr build, there's a URL in the comment at the top, which looks something like this:

```
Build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-...
```

which lists all of the detects which have been included. So if `fontface` is in this list, you know that Modernizr will either add `.fontface` or `.no-fontface` depending on the detection result.